# Custom data in Plotly tooltip not showing

Tags: javascript, graph, plotly, plotly.js

I'm trying to customize a tooltip in Plotly JS to show non-default data. For that, I followed the https://plotly.com/javascript/hover-text-and-formatting/ Advanced Hovertemplate example.

However, for options in my example:

```
 var data = {
       x : timestamps,
       y : values,
       mode : 'lines+markers',
       type : 'scatter',
       name : 'Test',
       hovertemplate: '%{y} %{name}'
    };
```

y value will appear but name will still be shown as %{name} in tooltip. Additionally, in browser log the following message appears: `Variable 'name' in hovertemplate could not be found!`.

The only alternative I found is defined here https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-display-variable-text-in-a-hover-template/22527 by using `customdata` variable, but it also has to be structured as an array in my case containing n instances of the same value. I guess this works but doesn't seem like a most prudent solution.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem previously and discovered that I needed to use %{data.name} instead of just %{name}.  I think I found this after reading hovertemplate's description and seeing this sentence: "The variables available in `hovertemplate` are the ones emitted as event data described at this link [https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#event-data."](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#event-data.%22)  If you go to that link, you'll see the "data" key in the event object.

Comment: You made my day! For my use case in python prepending 'data.' solved it, in fact also for the use of `customdata`. However, when I try the [example](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#adding-other-data-to-the-hover-with-customdata-and-a-hovertemplate) I need to omit the 'data.'. Not clear why - any thoughts?